# does dijkistra guarantee an admissible heuristic

Tags: algorithm, search, graph

We know that dijkistra is a modified version of A* algorithm where in the estimated cost is set to zero.My question is  the heuristic function used by dijkistra an admissible.
Apologies if the question does not make sense.This was asked in an interview one week ago ,and I don't recall the exact wordings.

Comment: yes if lengths between nodes are all >= 0... but if for some weird reason you can have negative weights then no.

Answer (score 1):

In A* algorithm H-cost is a heuristic and it is admissible, otherwise we wouldn't be able to find the shortest path.

Dijkstra uses heuristic which is constantly zero as H-cost is constantly zero. So it is also admissible as it doesn't overestimate the shortest path.

Comment: So can we say that Dijkistra is a relaxed version of A*.And although it's optimal my understanding is ,that it's not efficient as the number of nodes being expanded are more.Please correct me if I am wrong